# JavaFx - Table view not scrolling on Mouse Wheel ( disable Scrolling of Table View ), When put Table Cell a webview

Tags: javafx, webview, tableview, javafx-11

My scenario is I am using a webview one of the columns cell of the Table view, So, When I scroll mouse wheel on that column, table view Scrolling not fired, But, web View move something up and down, That means web View got the mouse scrolling, and for that reason table view is not scrolling.

So, My question is, is there any Solution that, on mouse scrolling, upon the webview, fire the table view scrolling behaviour, and that time stopped the scrolling behaviour of web view ?

```
@Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);



        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            updateTextFlow(highlightText.getValue());
            setGraphic(webView);
            //setGraphic(textFlow);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

At last I have got the idea on of So Answer. What I did :

```
ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) tableView.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");

        webView.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                event.consume();
                Node target = scrollBar;
                ScrollEvent retargettedScrollEvent = new ScrollEvent(target, target, event.getEventType(),
                        event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY(), event.isShiftDown(),
                        event.isControlDown(), event.isAltDown(), event.isMetaDown(), event.isDirect(),
                        event.isInertia(), event.getDeltaX(), event.getDeltaY(), event.getTotalDeltaX(),
                        event.getTotalDeltaY(), event.getTextDeltaXUnits(), event.getTextDeltaX(),
                        event.getTextDeltaYUnits(), event.getTextDeltaY(), event.getTouchCount(),
                        event.getPickResult());
              //  Event.fireEvent(target, retargettedScrollEvent);
                javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(target, retargettedScrollEvent);
               // System.out.println("webView.addEventFilter------------");
            }
        });
```

At that way, when I scroll upon the webview, The Whole tableView Start Scrolling, Alhamdulillah.